# I want to add custom button in products related list of opportunity? or Add Product URL Hacking

Tags: apex, visualforce, administration, urlhacking, button-overrides

I want to add custom button in related list of product same work like **add Product**  but view product based on my condition.

How can I do that? Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a button on opportunity product. setup --> Build-->Customize-->Opportunities-->Opportunity Products-->Buttons and Links

click on Buttons and Links.

Create a list button.

Now open any opportunity record. click on edit pagelayout --> goto product related list -->click on setting icon--> click on button -- >now add your newly created button on pagelayout and save.

if you want to open product selection page onclick of button then create button content source = URL

and add this URL below `/ui/opportunity/SelectSearch?relatedListId=PricebookEntry&addTo={!Opportunity.Id}`

you need to prepare URL like below

https://ratan-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/ui/opportunity/SelectSearch?relatedListId=PricebookEntry&addTo=0069000000J8O5q&PricebookEntrycol0=PRODUCT2.FAMILY_ENUM&PricebookEntryoper0=contains&PricebookEntryfval0=INDIA

It add the values in filter

```
PricebookEntrycol0=PRODUCT2.FAMILY_ENUM
PricebookEntryoper0=contains
PricebookEntryfval0=INDIA
```

If you want change the filter based opp values. You can use custom javascript button for condition and prepare the url and then open product selection page.

[image]

Comment: thanks.  this is correct but i have one custom field in product like Family , it will categories product by this field so i will create button only for one category . when i click on that button then i want to see only products with that category  . is it possible ?

Comment: if you look https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008p4XIAQ link there parameter `PricebookEntrycol0`

Comment: hey @ParthThakkar you need to prepare url like this https://ratan-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/ui/opportunity/SelectSearch?relatedListId=PricebookEntry&addTo=0069000000J8O5q&PricebookEntrycol0=PRODUCT2.FAMILY_ENUM&PricebookEntryoper0=contains&PricebookEntryfval0=INDIA

Comment: @ParthThakkar is it worked or not? Can you confirm so it will help other

Comment: NO  it will not work. it will populate in product filter page but not filter any value after click on filter and before on load.

Comment: @ParthThakkar have you tried? Try once then tell me If i am wrong. It will populate all the filter values and perform search